# Import Google Voice Contacts Into iPhone

Tags: iphone, contacts, google-apps

What I'd like to do is have my Google Voice contacts available on my iPhone, not the other way around.  I recently had to restore the phone to factory defaults and it's a pain to manually enter all them all.

When I make a new GMail e-mail account on my iPhone it won't let me import contacts from my Google account, but even if it did I don't want every single contact in my phone.  Google for some reason adds every single person I've ever sent e-mails to into my contacts list, which as you can imagine is quite a large list by now.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trim the contacts you have and setup google sync via exchange and it should only sync your contacts from "My Contacts"

Edit your contacts here:

http://www.google.com/contacts

how to set up your iPhone with google sync:

http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=138740&topic=14252

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to the Contacts tab of the GV sidebar.
2. Click the Export link at the top right.
3. Select which you want to export.
4. Use the Outlook CSV format if you've got a PC and the vCard format if you've got a Mac.
5. Import it to Outlook or Address book (depending on your system) and set iTunes to sync contacts to the iPhone from that program.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your iPhone with the Exchange Servers that Google has. I have mine set up for just Calendar and Contacts sync. For instructions, take a look over [here](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740). Also, take a look over at the Google Voice iPhone app - it's fairly useful, and it can (and indeed has for my dad at least) replaced Messages.App and Phone.App on his iPhone.

Comment: GVoice app doesn't help with this problem, though if Google cared it really should be able to easily import Google contacts to the iPhone address book.  It seems this app hasn't been significantly updated in years, and the graphics resolution and behavior seems stuck in pre-iOS 4 (iOS 6 was just announced and will be out by end-of-year).